# I have a trigger and I am freezing at working with more than one record on Custom object MapTesting__c

Tags: trigger, bulk

My task is I need to count number of times a record has been edited using Edit button after record has been created.

For this I created a field called `Edit_Counting__c (Number Type) and` also created one workflow on `MapTesting__c` to get the count that record has been edited using `ISCHANGED (Field Type).`

Later I created one more field called `Counting__c` and I created this trigger,

```
Edit_counting__c with Counting__c (maap.Counting__c = maap.Edit_Counting__c+1)
```

I am getting my output by using `Counting__c` value, but its working for only one record when I click edit button for one record respectively.

When I am trying to update more than one record using developer console, the `Couting__c` value does not effect to all the modified records. I do not know where I have done mistake. I also post my code below. Please check it and please could anyone help in this?

```
trigger MapTesting_Editable on MapTesting__c (after update) {

List<MapTesting__c> mmp= new List<MapTesting__c>();

List<MapTesting__c> mm = [select id, Edit_Counting__c,Counting__c from 
MapTesting__c where Id IN: Trigger.OldMap.keySet()];

    if(RecusrssionTrigger.flag){
        for(MapTesting__c maap:mm){
            RecusrssionTrigger.flag=false;
            maap.Counting__c = maap.Edit_Counting__c+1;
            mmp.add(maap);
        }
        update mmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your test class look like? this context may only be 1 `Trigger.newMap.keySet()`

Comment: How are you doing the "Bulk" and what is the deal with the recursion flag being what seems to be the revers to me. You are going to have to post more code for us to help. Also, review the debug logs as it will tell you exactly what it going on. How are you testing it to know it is not working?

Answer (score 2):

A before trigger would reduce the complexity a lot:

```
trigger MapTesting_Editable on MapTesting__c (before update) {

for(MapTesting__c map: trigger.new){
    maap.Counting__c = maap.Edit_Counting__c+1;

}

}
```

Is it just me or does your `RecusrssionTrigger.flag` seem to be backward in that it appears to be true before any recursion is possible?

You should also be checking the value of `maap.Counting__c` for null or you could get an error at that line

Comment: Hi Eric, My requirement is after update.

Comment: Good catch on that flag Eric..  What is your use case? Is this a homework assignment?  He's saying it doesn't need to be after update..

Comment: Then question your requirement...because your requirement using up queries, heap, cpu time, etc needlessly. If you insist on the after update the only thing I can see is the weird use of the flag. When you say bulk how are you performing the "bulk operation"

Comment: Yeah...... I am new Apex. Generally, i have done using before event. So now i am trying to do this using after update with more records.

Comment: @KSKumaar Check [this thread](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/128692/20721) to see when to use before and after triggers generally.

Comment: @KSKumaar - Your basic process for after update seems to be correct. Check that recursion flag. Also bulk is not one record at a time in the same transaction, it is a list of records. Those are the only two reasons off the top of my head, why your above code would do what you describe. Debug logs are your friend here and will point you to the exact cause. Have you reviewed them?